# Set Global default Ruby for RVM on machine with multiple (too many?) Rubies

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rvm

I am struggling to get Rails to deploy on a server that has:

- a factory installed Ruby (1.8.7) in `/etc/`
- an updated Ruby (1.9.2p290) in `/usr/local/bin/`
- the Ruby I want to be using(1.9.2p290) in `/usr/local/rvm/rubies`.

Is there a way to set a GLOBAL default Ruby in RVM for ALL users?

When I set default with `rvm --default 1.9.2@railspre` it'll work fine for that session. But, when I log back in the ruby switches back to the one in `/usr/local/bin`. And, due to RVM's hocus pocus, that I don't fully understand, I can't just edit the `$PATH` for it in `.bashrc`.

`$PATH` at login:

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/opt/subversion/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@railspre/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin
```

`$PATH` after `rvm --default 1.9.2@railspre`:

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@railspre/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/opt/subversion/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/X11/bin
```

No matter what (before or after changing RVM's default) `rvm default list` says the same thing:

```
$ rvm default list

rvm rubies

=> ruby-1.9.2-p290 [ ppc ]
```

Ideas?

**Edit- adding requested info**

```
$ type rvm | head -1
rvm is a function
$ which ruby
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby
$ whereis ruby
/usr/bin/ruby
```

Answer (score 1):

Please post the result of the following :

```
type rvm | head -1
rvm notes
which ruby
whereis ruby
rvm list known
```

Do =>

```
rvm use 1.9.2 --default
```

Being root and normal user do =>

```
echo '[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM function' >> ~/.bash_profile
source .bash_profile
```

Restart your pc and see if it works.

Comment: can you explain those `$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm` strings will do if in .bash_profile (which doesn't exist btw)? Not that I don't trust you just want to know how dangerous (and reversible) they are should they not work... Also, keep in mind that RVM on this server is a Multi-user install so NOT in any user's HOME folder.

Comment: added results of some of your commands above. `which ruby` and `whereis ruby` look odd!  didn't include `rvm notes` or `rvm list known` because they are long and look normal. `rvm use 1.9.2 --default` makes no apparent difference to `rvm --default 1.9.2`.

Comment: why did you install ruby being root ? rvm uninstall ruby-1.9.2 and as a normal user do, rvm install ruby-1.9.2

Comment: if you must know it's because this server WAS managed that way...and did fine...but it's become too troublesome to manage so now *trying* to move to an RVM environment…

Comment: Which operating system ? You are using system-wide ruby /usr/bin/ruby follow this => http://beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/